# Domain, log and squareroot

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have learned all these relations in highschool, such as:

$$\sqrt{a b}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$$
and

$$a\log{b}=\log b^a$$

But now I am finding out that it all depends on the domains whether such relations are true. For example:
$\log{x^2}=2\log{x}$ only if $x>0$

What are the general rules when applying basic relations with square roots and log when it comes to applicability regarding domain?

Comment: To answer the first part: $\sqrt{a b}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is true if both $a$ and $b$ are non negatives.

Comment: @imranfat Actually it is also true if one of them is positive and the other negative.

Comment: That depends how you introduce complex numbers. If you use the "quickfix" $\sqrt{-a}=i\sqrt{a}$, then yes. But it isn't particularly clean imo.